# Importing Microsoft .url file to bookmark (Firefox / Mac OS)

Tags: windows-xp, mac

I ran across a situation at work the other day where we were trying to move a pile of .url files on a Windows XP machine to bookmarks under Firefox on Mac OS X 10.5.8.  It proved very frustrating, as we didn't have access to the source machine anymore (where we could have exported the bookmarks properly).

Does anyone have a solution for that one?

Comment: any chance you'd pick an answer, to get this off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to convert .URLs to bookmarks is via a Windows PC that has Firefox on it (and seeing as you have .URL files at all I'm guessing you must have some access to a Windows box).

Put all the .URL files into the Favourites folder on the Windows box, open Firefox, goto `File` menu -> `Import...` and import the favourites into Firefox. You can then open Firefox's bookmarks manager from `Bookmarks` menu -> `Organise Bookmarks` and from there anything you export from the `Import and Backup` menu should be fully readable and importable by Mac Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This script works a bit better, a few more quotes needed basically

```
for i in *.url; do
  title=${i%%.URL}
  link=`grep -e "^URL=" "$i" | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
  echo '<a href="'"$link"'">'"$title</a>" >> bm3.html
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, Firefox on MacOS won't open .url files, right?

And [Web Location Converter](http://cverge.net/tools/) is an application that should convert .url files to .webloc files, which I *think* Firefox will open.  It says that it isn't 100% under Snow Leopard, but the only thing broken is the other direction, so you should be okay.

Here's an [AppleScript droplet](http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?p=380575#post380575) that would work to simply open the files if Firefox hadn't broken its AppleScript support at some point.

Either way, one you get them opened in Firefox, it should be trivial to then bookmark the lot of them.

Alternately, .url files are pretty simplistic.  You could throw some text processing at them to convert them into a simple html file pretty readily:

```
for i in *.URL; do
  title=${i%%.URL}
  link=`grep -e '^URL=' $i | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
  echo '<a href="'"$link"'">'"$title</a>" >> bm.html
done
```

You *ought* to be able to import that.  But I haven't tested the script or the import.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old problem, here is the [bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=361847). As I understand it, this is actually a file w/ URL "stuff" in it, and Firefox was leveraging some Windows-level facility that is not available on Mac OS X.